# aws lambda を使用して家のプリンタからプリントアウトする方法

Tags: aws-lambda

aws lambdaを使って、wifiにつないだ、家のプリンタから文書等をプリントアウトすることは可能でしょうか？
できれば、やり方や調べ方のアドバイスをお願いします。

Comment: TCP/IPのコネクションとして、AWSから自宅、もしくは自宅からAWS、どちらの方向に接続されることを想定されていますでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。そこらへんもよくわかっていないのですが、例えばファイル共有サービスなどをつくって、誰がaws上のラムダをスマホ等から発火して、最終的にプリントアウトされるのが理想です。実装的には、プリンタから5分に一回ほど要求することになるのでしょうか？同一wifi経由でプリントアウトする際は、スマホのボタン一つでいけるように、aws側から接続できるのでしょうか？そこらへんも、よくわかっていません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の記事を試してみることにしました。
RasPiを使用して、Lambdaで引っ張ろうと思います

[Raspberry Pi を使ってレシートプリンタから印刷してみる](https://blog.cles.jp/item/10886)